# JqGrid export functionality not working when custom url is provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I have one jqxGrid , that I want to  export. By default  jqWidget uses it own server url  instead of that I want to use my url.But for custom url  export is not workking.

code

```
var url=window.location.href
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls','data',true,null,false,url);
```

Comment: It seems that you use `jqxGrid` and **not** `jqgrid`. You should remove wrong tab from your question.

Comment: @Oleg thanks..updated

Answer (score 0):

The url should point to where the export file is hosted. Its definitely wrong to write window.location.href. If you don't have the export file, then you can export only through jQWidgets server.

Comment: But export file will be generated  so that is why I have given same url

Comment: the parameter is called serverURL so it should point to  the export's PHP file, not to a file generated  and based on your data

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by calling a function and getting the file through ajax call in that function, ajax call gets file from the location which I provide to it

```
$("#grid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', excelFileName, true, null, false, getPphFileForExport());
```

function definition is like below

```
getPphFileForExport: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"/jqWidgets/dataexport.php",
        success: function (data){
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

please note that '/jqWidgets/dataexport.php' is the location in my repository that is accessible to this call